# Search Data based on 2 conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, search

I'm trying to write a code to Search and Modify Data from the "Billing Masterlist" (Image 1) and pull it back inside the "Data Entry Form"(Image 2) based on 2 conditions (Image 3). The flow of the system should be like below:

1. Data from the Data Entry Form will be submitted to the Billing master **(Solved).**
2. If I need to modify or search the old data, I will need to go back to the Data Entry Form by clicking the Search button if it meets 2 conditions which are Year & Hospital (Refer to image 3). Then it will pull back the data from the Billing masterlist into the Data Entry Form. **(Unsolved)**

Image 1: Billing Masterlist
[image: Billing Masterlist]

Image 2: Data Entry Form
[image: Data Entry Form]

Image 3: Search
[image: Search]

For testing purposes here is the Spreadsheet for your reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CyALo_tE_75w1SCPCIiiqgToyYRAnZJKMdpBpW6G5mY/edit#gid=1949705865

The code I'm currently writing couldn't pull data to the Data Entry Form properly and I'm lost for idea

Here is the written code:

```
var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Billing Masterlist"
var SEARCH_COL_year = 0;
var SEARCH_COL_hospital = 1;

function searchStr() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry Form");

  var hospital = formSS.getRange("C5").getValue();
  var year = formSS.getRange("C6").getValue();

  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Billing Masterlist").getDataRange().getValues();
  var cont = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)

  {
    var row = values[i];

    if ((row[SEARCH_COL_year] == year) || (row[SEARCH_COL_hospital] == hospital))

    {

      var s = (8 + cont).toString();
      formSS.getRange("D8")setValue(row[0]);
      formSS.getRange("B8")setValue(row[3]);
      formSS.getRange("B12:B25" + s).setValue(row[3]);
      formSS.getRange("E12:E25" + s)setValue(row[4]);
      formSS.getRange("F12:F25" + s)setValue(row[5]);
      cont = cont + 1;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the "Data Entry" Form? Could you not just write a query? In any event the question includes only two lines of sample data. Would you please edit the question to supply sample data (not in an image and preferably in the body of the question) as well as an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue by adjusting the code with this new one

```
var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Billing Masterlist"
var SEARCH_COL_year = 0;
var SEARCH_COL_hospital = 1;

function searchStr() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry Form");

  var hospital = formSS.getRange("B7").getValue();
  var year = formSS.getRange("D7").getValue();

  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Billing Masterlist").getDataRange().getValues();
  var cont = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)

  {
    var row = values[i];

    if ((row[SEARCH_COL_year] == year && row[SEARCH_COL_hospital] == hospital ))

    {

      var s = (11 + cont).toString();
      formSS.getRange("B" + s).setValue(row[2]);
      formSS.getRange("E" + s).setValue(row[4]);
      formSS.getRange("F" + s).setValue(row[5]);
      cont = cont + 1;

    }
  }
}
```

Thank you to those who trying to help. Appreciate your effort in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use built-in [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en).

For example, in `!'Data Entry Form'B2`, enter

```js
=filter(!'Billing Masterlist'C7:D,!'Billing Masterlist'B7:B=C5,
                                  !'Billing Masterlist'A7:A=C6)
```

You can make use of the same formula for the remaining data you need to pull.

If you can use built-in functions, you should.